# Android App Signing issue even though change the certificate

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, sign, android-app-signing

Android App Signing issue, new key generated & uploaded in google play. when generating an app with the new certificate but still showing that app signed with my old certificate when I am checking "apksigner verify -print-certs -v package.apk"

I HAVE SIGNED NEW CERTIFICATE & UPLOADED IN GOOGLE PLAY.

WHEN I AM GOING TO CHECK THE UPLOAD CERTIFICATE THAT THE APP I AM GENERATING & IT'S SHOWING DIFFERENT KEY EVEN THOUGH I AM SIGNING WITH NEW KEY.

I CLEANED THE FLUTTER & TRYING TO GENERATE BUT STILL SHOWING THE SAME.

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: In my understanding, you have published an app to play store. But right now if u r publishing tje apk with same keystore u r getting an error. Correct?  There may be a possibility that your key is tempered. Because for every upload key must be same. If it is tempered, u have to request through Google Play service with your registered email yo reset it. It will take 4 to 5 working day.  I Hope that may help u.

Comment: No No, I have key but after signing with that it's showing different key I signed.